# insertar imagen en r

Tags: imagen, r-markdown

Estoy intentando mostrar una imagen en el markdown e indico la fórmula para insertar

pero[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] me indica que no encuentra la imagen como muestro

es en MAC que puedo hacer para que salga?

gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: como inserto la imagen en el markdown

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en tu uso de la sintaxis de markdown. En los archivos Rmarkdown debes usar bloques de código para que se puedan ejecutar. Al anteponer el símbolo `#` en tu código no solo haces que no se ejecute, sino que lo estás formateando como encabezado, esto te generará problemas a la hora de renderizarlo (botón "Knit").

Si quieres que el gráfico aparezca debajo del código automáticamente, debes ejecutar el código en un bloque. Hay una sintaxis especial.

````
```{r}
codigo() %>% de() %>% grafico()
```
````

También puedes insertar bloques de código ejecutables usando el atajo `Command+Option+I` en Mac.

La segunda opción es 1) guardar el gráfico como archivo local y 2) luego insertarlo como imagen usando sintaxis de markdown.

````
```{r}
grafico <- codigo() %>% de() %>% grafico()

ggsave("nombre_de_grafico.png", grafico)
```

![Caption de imagen]("nombre_de_grafico.png")
````